# Using reported speech, should I use "having passed" or "passing"?

Tags: word-usage

Using the reported speech, I would change the following sentence in these ways.

> "You have just passed your exam. Congratulations!" Tom said to me.
>   Tom congratulated me on having passed my exam.

> "Congratulations! You passed your exams." they said to Maya.
>   They congratulated Maya on passing her exams.

Can I write *Tom congratulated me on passing my exam*?

Comment: This is very unusual: *"Tom congratulated me on having passed my exam."*

Answer (score -1):

"Having passed" means that the event happened in the past and is complete.  "Passing" means the event is happening now, as in "I am passing the exam.", or recently happened as in your example.  In practice, the two forms are often used interchangeably.

A case where it matters would be "Having passed my exam, I was awarded a certificate."  In this case using "passing" would be incorrect.